# How can i find all the times between two given dates and time?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

```
private void GetTimeBetween()
        {
            DateTime a = new DateTime(2010, 04, 24, 13, 10, 00);
            DateTime b = new DateTime(2010, 04, 25, 13, 10, 00);
            Console.WriteLine(b.Subtract(a).TotalMinutes);
            double d = b.Subtract(a).TotalMinutes;
        }
```

I'm getting TotalMinutes 1440

But how can i make now that it will create a List with all the dates and time between this two dates between a and b but in jumps of 10 minutes ?

For example in the List the first item will be:

24/4/2010 13:10:00

Then ext item will be

24/4/2010 13:20:00

And so on until b

25/4/2010 13:10:00

In this format in the List or in other formats but the idea to get all the dates+time between the two given dates.

Comment: Start from the lower date and keep adding 10 minutes until the end date. Now put it in code

Comment: As @JeroenVannevel says, start  from the lower date and use `a.AddMinutes(10);` until you get to the end date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gee, sometimes its fun to overengineer things. There is an `Aggregate` function which turns a list into a scalar value - lets create one that goes the other way

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> Explode<T>(this T value, Func<T,T> next, Func<T,bool> limit)
    {
        var n = value;
        while(!limit(n))
        {
            yield return n;
            n = next(n);
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
DateTime a = new DateTime(2010, 04, 24, 13, 10, 00);
DateTime b = new DateTime(2010, 04, 25, 13, 10, 00);
var result = a.Explode(x => x.AddMinutes(10), x => x>b).ToList();
```

Live example: http://rextester.com/WCGZL87983

Comment: Seems okay, except for one issue. What if `a > b` ? Then your code would still return one result which is `value`. I would do something like this `var n = value; while(!limit(n)) { ...... }`

Comment: @PonasJustas very true.

Answer (score 0):

You could loop it:

```
var list = new List<DateTime>();
var start = new DateTime(2010, 04, 24, 13, 10, 00);
var end = new DateTime(2010, 04, 25, 13, 10, 00);
for (DateTime date = start; date <= end; date = date.AddMinutes(10))
    list.Add(date);
```

Answer (score -1):

> Try this

```
 var start = new DateTime(2010, 04, 24, 13, 10, 00);
 var end = new DateTime(2010, 04, 25, 13, 10, 00);
 for (DateTime date = start; date <= end; date = date.AddMinutes(10))
 {
     Console.WriteLine(date.ToString("dd/mm/yyyy HH:mm:ss"));
 }
```